# Custom methods in adapter are not resolving in android

Tags: android

I have 2 methods inside of adapter class.

```
addValues(brandMap);
setBrandMap(brandMap);
```

that I'm trying to call after async call. However, the compiler is complaining that it cannot resolve these methods. What is the issue?

This is complete class.

```
public class FragmentBrandList extends ListFragment {

    private String TAG =  getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Map<String, Brand> brandMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private Query query = database.getReference("brands").orderByChild("name");

    public FragmentBrandList() {
    }

    public static FragmentBrandList newInstance(int num) {
        FragmentBrandList f = new FragmentBrandList();
        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        adapter = new FragmentBrandList.MyAdapter(Utility.getBrandMap(), getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Brand brand = Utility.getBrands().get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityProductList.class);
                intent.putExtra("BrandId", brand.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Brand brand = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Brand.class);
                    brandMap.put(brand.getId(), brand);
                }
                Utility.setBrandMap(brandMap);

                adapter.addValues(brandMap);
                adapter.setBrandMap(brandMap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                Utility.displayToast("Failed to read value." + error.toException());
            }
        });
        return v;
}
```

Adapter class

```
private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<Brand> brandList = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context context;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            }
        }

        public MyAdapter(Map<String, Brand> brands, Context context) {
        //public MyAdapter(List<Brand> brands, Context context) {
            this.brandList = new ArrayList<>(brandMap.values());
            //this.brandList = brands;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void setBrandMap(Map<String, Brand> brandMap){
            this.brandList = new ArrayList<>(brandMap.values());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addValues(Map<String, Brand> brands){
            brandList.clear();
            brandList.addAll(brands.values());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_brand, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if (brandList != null && brandList.size() > 0) {
                Brand brand = brandList.get(position);
                Glide.with(context).load(String.valueOf(brand.getImage()))
                        .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .into(holder.imageView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return brandList.size();
        }
}
```

Comment: Replece "private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;" with  "privat FragmentBrandList.MyAdapter adapter"

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your adapter field as:

```
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
```

That means wherever you use it, you'll see it as just a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, which doesn't have your custom methods on it. It doesn't matter that you've assigned there a subclass of `RecyclerView.Adapter` that has extra methods. It is because you might've assigned there a different subclass that didn't have those methods.

If you want to use your custom methods then change the declaration to:

```
private MyAdapter adapter;
```

Then you can use all methods declared in `MyAdapter` and inherited from superclasses. The tradeoff is that you cannot assign there any other subclass of `RecyclerView.Adapter`, but thanks to that compiler can know you can always use your extra methods.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line.

```
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
```

As you are holding your custom adapter object in the Base reference, hence those methods of your custom adapter is not visible to you. Change the reference to the type of your Custom Adapter and it should work fine.